# why need to remove creation complete listener in its handler?

Tags: apache-flex

I found the following code snippet from this open source project [Loading Spinner](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1219018)

```
public function Spinner() {
    super();
    addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, handleCreationComplete);
}


private function handleCreationComplete(e:FlexEvent):void {
    removeEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, handleCreationComplete);
    if (autoPlay) {
        play();
    }
}
```

why the line of removeEventListener is needed? Do that mean a creationComplete event will be fired more than 1 time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason for removing the listener is this:
As long as an event listener is attached to an instance of a class, that listener can never be "garbage collected" until it is removed from the dispatcher, or until the dispatcher is also eligible for garbage collection. i.e. it will keep existing in memory as long as the application runs, even if you remove it from the stage and you explicitly set it to `null`.
That's why it's good practice to always clean up event listeners when they are no longer needed. You may avoid memory leaks.

Comment: You are not correct. Dispacther **can** be collected as listeners does not know about it. Listeners **can't** be collected because dispacher hold referneces to them in order to call them. And when dispatcher and listener are the same, there is no need to worry about any leaks. In this example we can cleanly see that author of the code doesn't understand what he has written. And in any case, today we have weak references for such cases.

Comment: @user1875642 I must admit I didn't know it was actually the other way around. Since my answer's been accepted and you didn't post your own, I edited mine to be more correct. That said, I disagree that using weak references is the solution. They tend te be erratic, especially in Flex applications where you don't have full control over your components. I just found [this excellent article on the subject](http://gingerbinger.com/2010/07/actionscript-3-0-events-the-myth-of-useweakreference/).